# Rcon Sending Command to Server

Tags: php, server, request

I would like to send custom text by web to my game server throught this script, but i dunno how to define the text inside input

Any tip or suggestion or fix?

the script is:

```
<?php
function send_command($ip,$port,$rcon,$command) {
    $fp = @fsockopen("udp://".$ip, $port, $errno, $errstr);
    if ($fp){
        $request = chr(1).chr(0).chr(242).chr(strlen($rcon)).$rcon.pack("S",strlen($command)).$command;
        fwrite($fp, $request);
    }
}

$name = "Owner";
echo "<input type='text' name='$msg'";

if (isset($_REQUEST['send'])) {
    send_command("192.168.1.69",36963,"asdasd","say ©255255255".$name.": ".$msg);
}
?>

<html>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="send">
    </form>
</html>
```

"Error "is:

Notice: Undefined variable: msg in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined variable: msg in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define your input's ID with a '$'. PHP interprets that as a variable. Name it 'msg'. You  may then reference it with `$_POST['msg']` or `$_GET['msg']`, depending on how you sent it to the PHP file.